# Unable to start MySQL daemon: segmentation fault

Tags: mysql, segmentation-fault, mariadb

MySQL daemon (well, actually is MariaDB daemon) doesn't start anymore. /var/log/mysql.err is empty. dmesg gives me this error:

> [ 1042.816803] mysql_upgrade[11409]: segfault at ffffffe0 ip b7523515
>   sp bf823300 error 5 in mysql_upgrade[b750b000+2b2000]

For what I know mysql_upgrade is used when you upgrade MySQL... I do not know why it's invoked at MySQL start, since I've not upgraded it (it's the latest version, fresh install).

It worked until yesterday and I do not know what I could have done... The only thing I changed is that I added these lines to my.cnf:

```
# *UTF-8*
character_set_server = utf8
collation_server = utf8_general_ci

# *STRICT MODE*
sql_mode = "REAL_AS_FLOAT, PIPES_AS_CONCAT, ANSI_QUOTES, TRADITIONAL"
innodb_strict_mode = ON
```

but I tried to uncomment them without success.

I'm using MariaDB 5.5.31 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem: it seems that you can't add spaces to sql_mode. This bug happens to MySQL as well. So you have to write:

```
sql_mode = "REAL_AS_FLOAT,PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ANSI_QUOTES,TRADITIONAL"
```

It seems a bug, since on [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi) and [MariaDB](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/sql_mode/) documentations have examples with whitespaces.

The strange fact is that I had to uninstall MariaDB and reinstall it to work again with it, but this time when I readded the sql_mode setting, started the daemon, removed the sql_mode and restarted the daemon, it worked and I had not to reinstall it another time.